# LINQ to get all elements of a list other than itself for each item

Tags: c#, linq

Given a list of integers such as `List<int> myList = new List<int> {5, 3, 7, 5, 7, 10}`, for each element in the list, I need to get a list containing all other elements of the list other than itself. For instance,

for the element 5, I need to get back {3, 7, 5, 7, 10}
for 3, I need to get back {5, 7, 5, 7, 10}
and so on.

I am able to do it in a naïve way using a nested loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count(); i++)
{
    otherThanItselfList.Clear();
    for (int k = 0; k < myList.Count; k++)
        if (k != i)
            otherThanItselfList.Add(inputList[k]);
}
```

I tried using `TakeWhile` and `SkipWhile` but not able to get the desired result. Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: Does it matter which of the duplicates is removed? Can the result for both 5 be same?

Comment: No, the duplicates shouldn't be removed.

Comment: How do you know that 5 is the first one in the list and not the second one though? They are the same thing.

Comment: How does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

For each item with index (idx), create a new list where it's not included:

```
myList.Select((_, idx) => myList.Where((_, thisIdx) => thisIdx != idx).ToList())
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count(); i++)
{
    otherThanItselfList.Clear();
    otherThanItselfList= myList.ToList();
    otherThanItselfList.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ and define a List<List> that contains List of other elements for each item using code below:

```
 var myList = new List<int> { 5, 3, 7, 5, 7, 10 };

 var myListOfList = myList.Select((_,i) => myList.Where((_,j) => i != j).ToList()).ToList();

 foreach (var item in myListOfList)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', item));
 }
```

In this code you can see each list of other printed with comma.

I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Note that that will skip duplicates as well - if the list were `{ 1, 1, 1 }` you'd end up with nothing, for example. I *suspect* the OP wants to skip by element index rather than element value, although it's not specified clearly.

Comment: If we want to have duplicates, myListOfList should change to this:
var myListOfList = myList.Select((x,i) => myList.Where((y,j) => i != j).ToList()).ToList();

Comment: The Guru Jon Skeet is right, I need to skip the index, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

When filtering

> all other elements of the list other than itself

we can use `Where`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    var otherThanItselfList = myList
      .Where((item, index) => index != i)
      .ToList();

    // otherThanItselfList contains all items except i-th
    // Let's have a look
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", otherThanItselfList));
}
```

However, if `myList` is long, recreating `otherThanItselfList` will be slow; let's use `LinkedList` instead:

```
LinkedList<int> otherThanItself = new LinkedList<int>(myList);
      
var node = otherThanItself.First;  
      
foreach (var item in myList) {
  var next = node.Next; 
        
  otherThanItself.Remove(node);
        
  // Let's have a look
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", otherThanItself));    
        
  if (next != null)     
    otherThanItself.AddBefore(next, node);      
        
   node = next;     
}
```